# Image as background for every artboard in the same file

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm currently designing mockups for an application, and every one of these screens has the same image background.

I was wondering if it's possible to, instead of copying the file on every artboard and thus increasing the `.ai` file size exponentially, there is a way to embed the file once, and then use it as some sort of background property for every artboard in the same `.ai` file.

Thanks in advance! I'm hoping it'll help reduce the file size of my mockups.

Answer (score 1):

Pieter, if you make the graphic a symbol it will place an instance of the graphic rather than another copy thereby reducing the file size. select your graphic drag it into the symbols palette and place on aboard 1. Cut from artboard then ctrl+alt+shift+v to paste on every artboard

Comment: So you're saying that it isn't possible to use it like a template for all artboards in one file? This solution does reduce file size, so that's already one requirement met, thanks!

Comment: It's not like indesign where you create a master template if that's the solution your after